# Passing C string back from DLL across Extern C

Tags: c++, string, dll

The toy program below works when it's all compiled in a single program but will it work if `getMessageFromNetwork` is moved into a DLL?

I am astoundingly bad at using/creating DLLs, my main fear is that I am passing references to bad memory around.

```
#include "string.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void getMessageFromNetwork(char* buffer, size_t bufferSize);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char errorMessage[500];
  getMessageFromNetwork(errorMessage, sizeof(errorMessage));
  std::string outString(errorMessage);
  std::cout << outString;
  return 0;
}



void getMessageFromNetwork(char* buffer, size_t bufferSize)
{
  const std::string errorMessageFromNetwork = "0123456789 this is a string from the network of uncertain length and termination";
  std::string localMessage = errorMessageFromNetwork;
  localMessage.resize(bufferSize);
  localMessage[bufferSize - 1] = '\0';
  strcpy(buffer, localMessage.c_str());
}
```

The only similar question I can find on stackoverflow is

[C string through dll boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349505/c-string-through-dll-boundaries)

and I don't *think* I'm making any of the mistakes that are being warned about in the two replies but I am not certain.

## EDIT

The main reason I worry is that a very senior engineer at work suggested that the correct way to pass a buffer into the function is:

```
getMessageFromNetwork(char** buffer, size_t bufferSize)
```

and then calling it like

```
char errorMessage[500]
getMessageFromNetwork((char**)&errorMessage, sizeof(errorMessage))
```

which I have just been completely unable to get working for several hours on friday when I was at the office.

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: But you don't pass any strings across dll boundary. You only fill buffer supplied and managed by the caller. However you should  add checks for null pointer and for `bufferSize` being sufficient to contain `localMessage.c_str()` (and probably return amount of bytes written).

Comment: Have you tried checking if it works from a *.dll*?

Comment: @CristiFati I would love to test from a DLL and I intend to do so tomorrow but the VPN to my office is down so I can't test on the DLL that exists already and I am truly astonishingly bad at DLL coding so I can't set it up at home.

Comment: `senior engineer at work suggested` depends on what is in the `buffer`

Comment: Are you sure the senior engineer didn't also suggest making the bufferSize parameter a size_t&, or changing the signature to return a size_t? He seems to be concerned with you truncating the message. He may want you to use realloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original function is absolutely OK, don't be confused by your collegues suggestions.

Comment: I sure hope you're right. I'll test tomorrow and report back if it worked.